# I am trying to fetch amazon prices using Jsoup on Java

Tags: java, web-scraping, fetch, jsoup

I want to get the prices of a amazon product and then put them into a spreadsheet with the price next to the time. I am trying to use Jsoup for this (and I am very new to this)
This is what I currently have.
I cant even get the price so that is what I need the most help with

```
/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package amazon;

/**
 *
 * @author kennethkreindler
 */
import java.io.IOException;

import org.jsoup.Jsoup;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Document;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Element;
import org.jsoup.select.Elements;
public class Amazonmain {

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     * @throws java.lang.Exception
     */

   public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        String url = "http://www.amazon.de/DJI-CP-PT-000498-Mavic-Drohne-grau/dp/B01M0AVO1P/";
        Document document = Jsoup.connect(url).userAgent("Mozilla/17.0").get();

        String question = document.select("span.priceblock_ourprice");
        System.out.println("Price is" + question);


        }
    }
```

Comment: How about simply using [their API](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSECommerceService/latest/DG/EX_RetrievingPriceInformation.html)?

Answer (score 4):

You have few issues here:

1. Your user agent is outdated, so you get a totally different response than you expect. Use a newer one.
2. `document.select` returns an `Element`, not `String`.
3. Your seletor is not right.
   Use the following code:

   ```
   String url = "http://www.amazon.de/DJI-CP-PT-000498-Mavic-Drohne-grau/dp/B01M0AVO1P/";
   Document document = Jsoup.connect(url).userAgent("Mozilla/49.0").get();
   Elements question = document.select("#priceblock_ourprice");
   System.out.println("Price is " + question.html());
   ```